# Performant way to load site navigation from a DB table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, caching, sqlite

I have been working on a Rails 4 app and my need is to store the main navigation of the app in a DB table. The reason is that the main navigation is a list of Categories. And these Categories are associated to other tables. I want my site navigation to be up to date with the list of Categories.

My concern doing so is that the app will make a DB query on every request. I was wondering if there is a way to cache but still have it invalidated when I change the Category in the DB.

What could be the best possible way to load the navigation from the table and yet not hit by the DB queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid hitting the DB every request, use memcache or redis to cache the result.

However, caching is a huge topic, and many caching strategies exist.  As your question hints at, cache expiration is the hard part of this topic, not caching.

When it comes to expiration techniques, on the database side Russian doll caching is now considered best practice.  If your data doesn't change (meaning you don't need to worry about cache expiration) you may be able to get way with page caching -- if so, count yourself lucky.  If it changes only occassionally, action caching might be in order.  Otherwise I highly recommend fragment caching for portions of your view page and model caching for individual methods that are time consuming when they fetch from the database.

Overall, when doing performance optimization with caching, **start high then go low**.  The gains you will get will be greater for less effort.

From a high to low, some types of caching available to you are:

- [HTTP caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/321-http-caching) (does not cache your server, but involves a user's browser caching content locally by reading HTTP headers)
- [Page caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/89-page-caching-revised) (memcache)
- [Action Caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/93-action-caching) (memcache)
- [Fragment caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/90-fragment-caching-revised) (memcache) or [Russian doll caching](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) (a type of fragment cache)
- [Model caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-model-caching-revised) (memcache)

#### Other resources to get you started:

Railscast on cache keys (Russian Doll Caching relies on them to work):  http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests

Advanced caching guide: http://hawkins.io/2012/07/advanced_caching_revised/

Not free, but I found this series was what really let me understand various forms of caching correctly:
http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/rails-4-1-performance-fundamentals